Because progress_dialog 1.2.4 doesn't support null safety and no versions of progress_dialog match >1.2.4 <2.0.0, progress_dialog ^1.2.4 is forbidden
After running flutter pub get, the following error occurs
click on the image
I have also changed the version bound to >=3.2.4 <4.0.0, but still this error is coming.
Also this is the output when VS COde runs flutter pub,
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety.
The current Dart SDK (3.4.3) only supports null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
exit code 65
--
[attendance_management_system] flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.4.3.
Because progress_dialog 1.2.4 doesn't support null safety and no versions of progress_dialog match >1.2.4 <2.0.0, progress_dialog ^1.2.4 is forbidden.
So, because spo_balaesang depends on progress_dialog ^1.2.4, version solving failed.
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
exit code 1

Sounds like you have some really ancient packages. Time to update them? The first hit on google is https://pub.dev/packages/progress_dialog_null_safe
